# Firing global variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables

I need to store the H1 content from another page into a var that I can access later on my code. I've come up with the following code:

```
var h1Text;
$.get('p1.html', function(data) {
    h1Text = $('<div>', {html: data }).find("h1").text();
    console.log("Test 1 = " + h1Text);
}, "html");

//some code here

//some code there

//another code here

console.log("Test 2 = " + h1Text);
```

The H1 content from the other page:

```
<h1 id="Title">Camp. Bras. Stock Car - 2ª Bateria</h1>
```

But when I look at my console, it says:

```
Test 2 = undefined
Test 1 = Camp. Bras. Stock Car - 2ª Bateria
```

Test 2 should run after Test 1, isn't? Is this why Test 2 if giving me 'undefined' value? I need to access var 'h1Text' later AFTER it's stored. What Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test 2 gets run before Test 1 because $.get needs to wait for a response and calls the success function when it got one. If you need to access h1Text you should do it after you got the data. So depending on your code you should call the functions that use h1Text from inside the success function you provided to get.

Comment: I wrap up some of the code I needed with the $.get as part of what you've mentioned and it worked. Thanks a lot :)